# How will credit card purchases NOT fall under the guidlines of the new Supreme Court ruling?

Tags: encryption

The intent of this new ruling by the Supreme Court is for anonymous networks but, when doing forensics on a wire in such a manner as to present to a judge, you can't tell what's inside those packets.

Also, an encryption session from the peer to peer client WASTE has a 256 encryption key in the header and that is it. WASTE would certainly fall under the criteria under the new ruling BUT, as soon as you class WASTE into the mix, a regular credit card purchase fits like a glove too!

Tor ban article:
http://themerkle.com/fbi-can-obtain-a-warrant-if-you-run-tor-come-december/

The ruling:
http://www.supremecourt.gov/orders/courtorders/frcr16_mj80.pdf

The part that sucks:

> 'A magistrate judge ... has authority to issue a warrant to use remote
>   access to search electronic storage … if: (A) the district where the
>   media or information is located has been concealed through
>   technological means;'

Whats to prevent to cops from busting down your door for making a credit card purchase?